# Bluetooth headset has no audio on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, sound, bluetooth, pulseaudio, pipewire

After logging into my user account, I can pair my Bluetooth headset, but it has no audio and the media doesn't play. Both video or audio stops playing. Disconnecting my headset is working fine, but reconnecting again stops playing streaming sites are asking to reboot my device.

I have tried everything I could find on AskUbuntu. Reinstalling `pipewire`, deleting the `PulseAudio` config directory, Nothing had helped. But one thing I'm doing is to work my headset to connect. While booting my machine, pair my devices that only works fine.